# CSS Radial Clip

Tags: html, css

I have a image of a circle (png) and I'd like to use `clip` to mask a portion of it. Is there such a type of radial clip? (Say I wanted to convert the circle to a pie chart e.g 32% only) with the clip mask

Edit: Perhaps tips on a SVG overlay would be nice if this isnt possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using canvas (and a very small bit of jquery to get node references):

```
var ctx = $( '#canvasTag' )[0].getContext( '2d' );

// draw your image
ctx.drawImage( $( '#imgTag' )[0], x, y );

// change composite operation so that only the image below the arc below shows
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';

// draw part of a circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc( x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false ); // draw outer arc
ctx.lineTo( x, y );                                   // draw to center
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```